# Difference between "now" and "right now"

Tags: meaning, differences

Is there any difference between the two following sentences?

> - We can't connect to Outlook right now.
> - We can't connect to Outlook now.

Comment: [Right now](http://onelook.com/?w=right+now). [Now](http://onelook.com/?w=now).

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Using *right now* emphasizes the time and implies that some condition is currently being experienced that prevents the connection but with the expectation that it will be corrected at some point in the future.

> We can't connect right now, but hopefully it will be fixed in an hour.

Using just *now* may imply that some general condition has changed that is not temporal in nature:

> You asked me to disconnect that cable, but I can't connect to Outlook now.

or it might be used in the exact same way as *right now* albeit with perhaps a little less emphasis on *this exact moment*.

Comment: I don't agree that plain *"[not] now"* actually *implies* a non-temporal reason why not. It's just that *"[not] **right** now"* very much *does* imply some temporary obstacle - which by further implication isn't expected to apply at some point in the future. So *"not right now"* always means *"probably/certainly later"*, whereas *"not now"* in and of itself says nothing about whether it's because of some recent but permanent change in the situation, or because it's not possible *at this exact moment*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, One might say, I can't connect *now* and mean *at this time*.

Comment: A man could say to his "broody" wife *"I don't feel like trying for another child **right now**, dear."* Then later that day (having been to the vasectomy clinic) he could say *"I can't father a child **now**"*. But if she didn't know where he'd been, the wife wouldn't necessarily realise her hopes had in fact been *permanently* dashed.

Answer (score 2):

*Right* often adds emphasis, as in ‘I want you to do it right now.’ In your example *right now* means ‘at exactly the present moment’, but it leaves the reader with the hope that a connection might be possible in the not too distant future.

Comment: Yes - _right now_ is often used as a hedged (ameliorated) form, sounding less abrupt than _now_ in a refusal (a negative construction): 'I'm sorry, I can't come right now.' Strangely, in an imperative construction, it adds bite: 'Do it _right now_!'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, right now means at "this exact moment". But "now" gives a longer lapse of time--perhaps in the next hour or so. "Right now" is also a panicked expression whereas "now" gives the feeling of being more relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following examples:

> - I want you to do it now.
> - I want you to do it right now.

Both sentences convey the same general meaning.  The second adds emphasis to encourage expeditious response.

Now consider:

> - We can connect to the internet now.
> - We can connect to the internet right now.

The first sentence indicates that we can connect at this very moment and leaves open the possibility, if not the likelihood that the connection may be ongoing.

However, the second sentence also indicates immediate access. However, it does not suggest ongoing availability, and may even suggest potential loss of access if not exercised soon.

Similarly:

> - We cannot connect to the internet now.
> - We cannot connect to the internet right now.

The first indicates no present access and perhaps ongoing lack of access. [*We cancelled our service.*] The status has changed from *yes* to *no*.

The second sentence conveys immediate access with no indication of ongoing status, or perhaps the tentativeness of the *no* status.  [*I'm not sure how long the power outage will last.*]

As in most writing, context will shape the interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

"Right now" is more prevalent in American english than in British.  It seems to follow a trend of "why use one word when two will do?".  Another example is "next up" rather than "next".  In Britain we would tend to say "at present".

Answer (score 0):

"Right now" is endemic in modern speech.  Now is too short a word to be emphasised effectively.  Other examples are "right here" and "right there".  It seems that "now" is not soon enough in today's "now" society.  I'm just waiting to hear "right now, right now".

Comment: But, as explained above, in OP's example, 'right' is not used as an emphasiser, but as an ameliorater.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, as it has become popular in street slang, simply adds emphasis to the preceding verbiage, as in, Are you kidding me right now? It implies nothing relating to past nor future.